# FTP put uploads file with zero size

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file from the local machine drive to a server.

I uploaded the file with the following code but it uploads the file with 0 byte size or a blank file.

Also, I did not get all the file path of the local file. It shows the server path. For example, if my local file is on D:/abc/abc.txt, it shows /public_html/abc.txt

Please help.

```
<?php
echo "hi";
echo "\n";

$host = '000.000.00.000';
$usr = 'userName';
$pwd = 'password';

$temp =  $_FILES["file"];
$local_file = realpath($_FILES["file"]["name"]["r"]);

$ftp_path = "/public_html/Download/".$_POST['file'];

echo "This is file to Upload :";
echo "\n";

print($local_file);

// connect to FTP server (port 21)
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");

// send access parameters
ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");

// perform file upload
print ("This is ftp path : ");
print($ftp_path);
print("New line : ");

$upload = ftp_put($conn_id,  $ftp_path, $local_file , FTP_ASCII , 0);

print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
print ("\n") ;

ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_FILES['file']['name']` is the name of the file on the client machine, not the server. The upload is put into `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` on the server, so this is the file that you should send with FTP.

You can use `$_FILES['file']['name']` when setting `$ftp_path`, so that the destination file will have the same name as the user's original file. `$_POST['file']` doesn't exist -- file uploads are only put in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: i also try that one but result is same.. :-(

Comment: I just added a problem you have with `$ftp_path`.

Comment: Barmar i Used following line instead but it gives me error while uploading .. plz help  **$local_file = realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);** **$ftp_path = "/public_html/Download/".$_FILES['file']["name"];**

Comment: What does the HTML of the `<input type="file">` look like?

Comment: error means in FTP error log it shows unexpected error and also in **print($ftp_path);** does not show any file name.  **print (!$upload)** shows cannot upload message ..

Comment: What does `var_dump($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])` show?

Comment: It shows null. and HTML for input here '<td><input name="file" type="file" /></td>'

Comment: Does the form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? That's required for file uploads.

Comment: thanks  a lot barmar .. that was the issue.. now file gets uploaded with data.. but when we try to upload pdf file it allow to upload but show damaged file when we try to open it ..is that due to ASCII or BINARY option ??

Comment: Yes, make sure you use binary mode in FTP for PDF files.

Comment: what if any kind of file i have to upload not just pdf? does binary allow to upload text or doc file ?

Comment: Most files should be uploaded in binary mode. Only plain text files should be uploaded in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **passive mode**

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
ftp_put($conn_id,  $ftp_path, $local_file , FTP_ASCII , 0);
```